# Android Gmap v2 unfortunately has stopped using SherlcokFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, actionbarsherlock-map

[image]I dont know what wrong with  my code, i have spent a half a day and searching around the google to solve this one, but no luck, i have imported google lib, bu still no luck either,my anndroid app still unfortunately has stopped when using `map = fragment.getMap();` inside `SherlockFragment`, if not use `getMap()` the map will show nicely, but when i call it the map stoped, here is my code, hope there is the way to solve this

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetaActivity extends SherlockFragment {
    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;

    // -6.240344, 106.838422
    private final LatLng SME_TOWER = new LatLng(-6.234813, 106.826731);
    private final LatLng SME_TOWER_1 = new LatLng(-6.236637, 106.824671);
    private final LatLng SME_TOWER_2 = new LatLng(-6.237938, 106.827031);
    private final LatLng SME_TOWER_3 = new LatLng(-6.232040, 106.826334);

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_peta, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean lokasi = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!lokasi) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());
            alertDlg.setMessage("Pendeteksian Lokasi Tidak Aktif");
            alertDlg.setCancelable(false);
            alertDlg.setPositiveButton("Cek Setting",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

            alertDlg.create().show();
        } else {
            if (map == null) {
                map = fragment.getMap();
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());
                LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());
                // map.moveCamera(
                // CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,
                // 14.0f));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SME_TOWER,
                        14.0f));
                // map.addMarker(new
                // MarkerOptions().position(userLocation)).setTitle("Halo, PILAR CIPTA SOLUSI");

                Marker tampil = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(SME_TOWER)
                        .title("Puri Denpasar Hotel Jakarta")
                        .snippet("Kuningan Kota Jakarta Selatan")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                tampil.showInfoWindow();

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(SME_TOWER_1)
                        .title("Pelaksanaan Peremajaan Pengurus RT dan RW di Kelurahan Kuningan Barat")
                        .snippet("Nilai Anggaran Rp.  20,170,000")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(SME_TOWER_2)
                        .title("Penyediaan Jasa TALI Kantor Kelurahan Kuningan Barat")
                        .snippet("Nilai Anggaran Rp. 146,000,000")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(SME_TOWER_3)
                        .title("Pelaksaan Kegiatan Posyandu dan Pemberian Makanan Tambahan (PMT)")
                        .snippet("Nilai Anggaran Rp.184,000,000")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            }
        }
    }

    class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
            myContentsView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

            return myContentsView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

here is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Lots of fancy layout -->   

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

here is my manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="appinventor.ai_wenkhairu.Pantura"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="appinventor.ai_wenkhairu.Pantura.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FotoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_foto" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PetaActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_peta" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAsgga.................." />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**update, here is my logcat**

```
08-26 02:23:54.862: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 8% free 2457K/2648K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
08-26 02:23:55.006: I/dalvikvm-heap(16199): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.102MB for 6898332-byte allocation
08-26 02:23:55.018: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 9193K/9388K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
08-26 02:23:55.026: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 9193K/9388K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 7ms
08-26 02:23:55.142: D/libEGL(16199): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
08-26 02:23:55.142: D/(16199): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8037100, tid 16199
08-26 02:23:55.162: D/libEGL(16199): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
08-26 02:23:55.166: D/libEGL(16199): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
08-26 02:23:55.266: W/EGL_emulation(16199): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 02:23:55.290: D/OpenGLRenderer(16199): Enabling debug mode 0
08-26 02:23:57.366: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 233K, 4% free 9960K/10328K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
08-26 02:23:57.394: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 11059K/11432K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-26 02:23:57.442: I/dalvikvm-heap(16199): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.342MB for 2536932-byte allocation
08-26 02:23:57.454: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 13537K/13912K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
08-26 02:23:57.462: D/dalvikvm(16199): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 13537K/13912K, paused 4ms+0ms, total 10ms
08-26 02:23:57.646: W/EGL_emulation(16199): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 02:23:57.702: W/EGL_emulation(16199): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 02:23:59.490: D/TilesManager(16199): Starting TG #0, 0xb8299a78
08-26 02:23:59.510: D/TilesManager(16199): new EGLContext from framework: b801e3f0 
08-26 02:23:59.510: D/GLWebViewState(16199): Reinit shader
08-26 02:23:59.754: D/GLWebViewState(16199): Reinit transferQueue
```

Comment: What is in your Logcat?

Comment: I have edited my question, by the way, i am not using emulator, i am using real devices to try this out

Comment: This is the debug log. There is en error log, too. Are u using Eclipse? :)

Comment: yes I am, there is no error in my log cat, i think red one is error log, but thereis no red color log in my logcat

Comment: select the dropdown and select "error". It will show you the stack trace of your crash.

Comment: Just one, here is `08-26 02:23:54.722: E/Trace(16199): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Not this log! When the app crashes, check the error log. It will show you the cause of crash!

Comment: In the logcat, there is a drop down which will give you an "error" option. When your app crashes, go to that section. You will get a lot of red text and it will also show you the cause of error.

Comment: I have attach the image of my eclipse, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's my mistake, i was not put the map inside ready fragment, onCreateView Google map doesn't loaded yet so the getMap(). i have to extends the fragment into MapFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

replace `your_package_name` with *your* package name.

and oh god, why are you posting your API key in a public forum?

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIz--------" />
```